# Trekking in Georgian Tusheti region? Safety?

Tags: safety, georgia-country, trekking

We're planning a hiking trip to the Georgian Greater Caucasus. But does anybody know issues about safety?

1. Terrorism (Chechnya, Dagestan just on the other side of the range)?
2. Minefields along border between Russia and Georgia?
3. Bears?

Comment: You might also be interested in [Outdoors.SE].

Comment: The borders are pretty heavily guarded, so rather unlikely to encounter any problems. People are extremely hospitable there, especially if you are not Russian, so I would not expect any problems. But yes, there are bears in the mountains.

Answer (score 8):

1. You are quite safe if you have no European good-looking girls in your company. If you have such girls you might be in big trouble, because [Bride kidnapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bride_kidnapping) is still a popular ritual in Georgia and Chechnya.
2. Pass the border between Georgia and Russia is better in Kazbegi (Other roads go through Abkhazia and North Ossetia - if you want to visit those countries, it's better to enter from the Russian side.) On the map I pointed out Kazbegi with a yellow circle [image: map of Georgia]
3. And, of course be aware of bears. Remember: if you see a bear, don't feed it, don't try to run, don't scream and don't make fast movements. The best way to act is just stay still and don't move. The bear is a intelligent beast and will never attack you first. [image: bear riding]

Comment: Bear riding entirely optional ;)